# UITextView Off Center and Not Scrolling

Tags: ios, scroll, xcode5, uitextview

I have a textview and I would like to be able to scroll through it and read the text, but as of now I can't scroll. I have user interaction enabled also, Thats my first problem. My second problem is that the text is off centered. If you have any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

iOS Simulator:
http://gyazo.com/150b994584a2e7dc42f96b0f4d889587

My Code:

```
_tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 320, 568)];
_tv.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.";
_tv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_tv.editable = NO;
_tv.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
[self.view addSubview:_tv];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITextView` will not be scrollable unless the text content exceeds the frame. In this case I can see that your frame is 568, therefore you will not have scrollable text unless the text exceeds this height.

Secondly, your text is off centre because you probably have not used `contentInset` of your top layout. You need to either set the contentInset, or move the text view down completely.

Btw, it's also a good idea to consistently use `YES/NO` boolean value instead of slipping `TRUE`. Inconsistencies like this might lead to very hard to find bugs.